# .NET ServiceInstaller get too much time for uninstall services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, service

we have some Setup Project wrote in Visual Studio 2008 in C# that installs and uninstalls services with ServiceInstaller class.
When I install the services this don't get too much time, but when I uninstall with following  code the process for each service get few seconds (and we have many services):

```
ServiceInstaller si = new ServiceInstaler();
string path = string.Format("/assemblypath={0}", strServiceExecutablePath);
string[] cmdline = { path };

InstallContext context = new InstallContext(string.Empty, cmdline);
si.Context = context;
si.ServiceName = strServiceName;
si.Uninstall(null);
```

Some one know why?

Here I want to ask some related question.
What difference between working of:

```
InstallUtill /u exePath
```

when it uninstall service
and:

```
sc delete serviceName
```

And why when I delete some record from registry from CurrentControlSet\services I still see the service in services.msc but with:

```
<Failed to read description. Error code:2
```

In description?
From where I need to delete service manually for delete it complitely?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0):

[`InstallUtil /u exePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx) will uninstall an application by calling the uninstaller part of your setup.

[`sc delete serviceName`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true) will delete a service subkey from the registry. It does not uninstall an application - but can be part of an uninstall procedure.

Regarding your `Failed to read description. Error code:2` error see this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverGP/thread/631323bf-9348-4bc1-97c4-7637a3c99f25). Most likely you only crippled your service but did not uninstall it. Run `sfc /scannow` and check the log.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I read the linked forum thread, and I see that it is not my case. There the problem is like I see, that GPO don't download the file, but my problem is, that after I remove the key from registry, services.msc still remember the record in some other place (may be in some hidden file that must be checked by sfc), so my question is: where else Windows stores information about services?